# MongoDB find all with value of undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi I have accidently update some of the records in mongodb with a value of undefined by writing some vanila javascript inside NoSQLBooster IDE. Problem is that records exist but when I ran $exists to true, it shows the records in Robo3T but not in NoSQLBooster. How ever when I ran email is equal to undefined it doesn't return any records however records exist. Here is the sample query and screenshot of result

```
 db.customer.find({source:'some value',"email":{$exists: true}})
   .projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
```

[image]

How do I query and correct those records. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can query for the documents where `email` is `undefined` by using the [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#op._S_type) operator:

```
db.customer.find({source: 'some value', email: {$type: 'undefined'}})
```

Note that the undefined type is listed as deprecated in [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#document-type-available-types), but it still works for now.

Querying for `email: null` will also return these documents, but that will also include documents where `email` is missing or set to `null`. As such, you'd need to further qualify the query with two more terms to exclude those:

```
db.customer.find({$and: [
    {source: 'some value'},
    {email: null}, 
    {email: {$not: {$type: 'null'}}}, 
    {email: {$exists: true}}]})
```